# Как расположить несколько div в одну строку

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap, веб-дизайн

Надо расположить несколько div'ов в одну строку. Пробовал: `display:inline-block; float:left;`. Увы, ничего не помогло. Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="p-4">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;padding: 20px;" >Заголовок</h1>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8" style="background-color:purple;height: 680px;display: inline-block;float: left;"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8" style="height:auto;float: left;">
            <h2 class="p-4">Второй заголовок</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" style="background-color: red;height: 680px;display: inline-block;float: right;"></div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Надо расположить блок красного цвета рядом с блоком фиолетового цвета.
Вот какой результат я хочу получить :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете показать, какой вы результат хотите получить в и тоге? Как минимум для второго заголовка блок занимает 8 колонок (когда их всего 12)

Comment: @OliverPatterson, Прошу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строку с блоком нужно было вставить перед вторым заголовком.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="p-4">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;padding: 20px;" >Заголовок</h1>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8" style="background-color:purple;height: 680px;display: inline-block;float: left;"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" style="background-color: red;height: 680px;display: inline-block;float: right;"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8" style="height:auto;float: left;">
            <h2 class="p-4">Второй заголовок</h2>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Чтобы увидеть нормально результат - нажмите "На всю страницу".

Comment: Да, это помогает, но я хочу чтобы на смартфонах сначала отображался "Второй заголовок", а потом уже блок. Или так нельзя ?

Comment: Кхм.. С бутстрапом плохо знаком, да и не нравится он мне) Попробуйте освоить гриды, думаю будет проще)

Comment: Ок, спасибо за помощь. Отмечу как ответ, так как это всё равно помогло)

Comment: Можно еще такой вопросик.. Почему вы стили пишите в атрибуте `style`?

Comment: Не знаю, мне так удобнее. Но я сделал этот файл чтобы, показать. На самом деле я использую отдельные CSS файлы.